# The Haramain Railway or Mecca-Medina Railway

Tags: high-speed-rail, mecca, medina

This is an extension on the other question about Mecka:

Is it allowed as a non-moslem to take the train to Mecka, stay in the nearabouts of the station and then take the train to Medina ?

Without trouble ie risking being kicked out (one commenter wanted the restrictions on moving in the holy cities removed but that for me is entirely up to the moslem world to decide itself !)